# How to get specific images Resource from Assets Folder?

Tags: java, android, imageview, resources, assets

I have 8 different plant species images under assets folder,  I cached the 8 images assets filename (corresponding to the path, E.g foxtail.png, orchid.png)   in the assets directory in a database. (Plus other information)

I'm 'displaying the 8 plants in a RecyclerView. Clicking on any of the plants opens the Detail Activity. (Passing the image filename as saved in the asset folder E.g  foxtail.png)

How do i pick the specific image file in the assets folder that matches the file name that was passed to Detail Activity and set it to an ImageView??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

**Open the file as a stream**

```
InputStream imageStream = null;
try {
    // get input stream
    imageStream  = getAssets().open("foxtail.png");
    // load image as Drawable
    Drawable drawable= Drawable.createFromStream(imageStream, null);
    // set image to ImageView
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }
catch(IOException ex) {
    return;
}
```

Finally remember to close the stream with

```
if(imageStream !=null){
    imageStream.close();
}
```

or

**moving your images in the res/drawable folder** you can load the images with:

```
String yourImageName = getImageNameFromDB();
int resId= getResources().getIdentifier(yourImageName, "drawable", "com.example.yourpackegename.");
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageDrawable(resId);
```

or

with **something like this** (always with the images into res/drawable):

```
private enum Plant {
    foxtail, orchid, xyz;
}

String value = getPlantFromDB();
Plant plant = Plant.valueOf(value); // surround with try/catch

switch(plant) {
    case foxtail : 
       resId= R.drawable.foxtail
       break;
    case orchid : 
       resId= R.drawable.orchid
       break;
    default : 
       resId= R.drawable.xyz
       break;
Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(resId);
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a tag on each ImageView/View using the Resource Drawable Id eg. R.drawable.foxtail

eg. `imageView.setTag(R.drawable.foxtail)` OR `view.setTag(R.drawable.foxtail)`

When one is selected, get the tag and send it to the next activity:

Then check again eg.

```
imageTag = getIntent().getIntExtra("chosenPlant");

if ( imageTag == R.drawable.foxtail ){
    //Perform action if this pic was selected (foxtail.png)
    newImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.foxtail);
} else ...
```

Comment: The image isn't in android resource folder, it is saved  in the assets/ directory, I  can't reference it like R.drawable.foxtail

Comment: Could you move it to the drawable folder? It would make the process easier

Answer (score 0):

You could create an array of int containing the resources ids.

```
int images[]={
        R.drawable.image_1,
        R.drawable.image_2,
        R.drawable.image_3,
        R.drawable.image_4,
        R.drawable.image_5,
        R.drawable.image_6,
        R.drawable.image_7,
        R.drawable.image_8
 };
```

In your database store image ids corresponding to the image positions in the resources array.

```
| id | image_id | information |
-------------------------------
| 0  |   2      |   info_0    |
| 1  |   0      |   info_1    |
| 2  |   4      |   info_2    |
```

So when you fetch rows from database, you can use image_id to retrieve the corresponding image from the array

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageResource(images[image_id]);
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be possible if the images were in the drawable folder,  but all the images are saved in assets/ directory. How do i read/reference them and display it.

Comment: You cannot guarantee that the id remain the same forever